# D3 DataMaps: How to stack bubbles based on radius?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I am using D3.js DataMaps for a Bubbles map. The problem of my map is that the biggest bubble is stacked on top of every other bubble. How do i get to sort these bubbles based on the radius??

Answer (score 1):

since the bubbles data is an array of objects you could use a custom sort function like this

```
myBubblesData.sort(function(a, b){ 
  if (a.radius < b.radius) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.radius > b.radius) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

to return the objects sorted in the opposite order, just reverse the '1' and '-1' return statements.